# SQL BETWEEN case sensitivity

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to create a BETWEEN parameter that returns values that are alphabetic (i.e. between A-Z and a-z inclusive). Is there a way to do this without using two BETWEEN clauses?

Comment: do an UPPER or LOWER (or UCASE or LCASE) on the thing you are comparing against.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what platform you are using

```
WHERE UPPER(fieldname) BETWEEN 'A' and 'Z'
```

or

```
WHERE UCASE(fieldname) BETWEEN 'A' and 'Z'
```

you might want to get rid of some pesky spaces

```
WHERE UPPER(TRIM(fieldname)) BETWEEN 'A' and 'Z'
```

This will be slow, we can't use fieldname in an index if we run a function on it.  So we are forcing a tablescan, which means two betweens and an or will be faster if fieldname is indexed and the table has some number of rows.